# Tabular Google Analytics data in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics

I have about 50 separate websites.

Instead of switching between Google Analytics property views for 30 minutes, is there a way I can see those propertys' vital stats in a table in a Google Sheet?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a script calling the API.

But the easiest way in my opinion is to install the *Google Analytics Add-on* [link here](https://gsuite.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/google_analytics/477988381226)

> **Overview**
>   Access all of your Google Analytics data in Google Spreadsheets.
>   The Google Analytics spreadsheet add-on brings you the power of the Google Analytics API combined with the power of data manipulation in Google Spreadsheets. With this tool, you can:
>
> - Query data from multiple views (profiles).
> - Create custom calculations from your report data.
> - Create dashboards with embedded data visualizations.
> - Schedule reports to run automatically so your data is always current.
> - Easily control who can see these data and visualizations by leveraging Google Spreadsheet’s existing sharing and privacy features.

More here with common use cases : https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on